# Currently listed solution to .replace() not fixing my issue

Tags: python

I have just tried the syntax suggested on a previous question similar to mine and it has not worked for me. I have tried:

```
newvar = str(oldvar)
newvar = newvar.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ' ')
```

and I have tried:

```
newvar = oldvar.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ' ')
```

My full (relevant) sections of code are here:

```
URLS = myurls2.values()

# Retrieve a single page and report the url and contents
def load_url(key, url, timeout):
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
    return conn.readall()


# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, key, url, 60): (key, url)
                 for key, url in myurls2.items()}
    c = 0


    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        key, url = future_to_url[future]    

        try:
            data = str(future.result())
            data2 = str(data)
            data2 = data2.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ' ')
            print(data2)
            d = open(filepath,"w")
            d.write(data2)
            d.close()
```

Dictionary values are converted to urls that are submitted to the relevant website then at the end I wish to convert them into a string and remove the characters listed in the replace statement.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to mention what your issue is.

Comment: its not replacing the values i am asking it to.

Comment: Yes it is. But probably your string is not what you think it is. Please show it and restate the problem you described in the earlier question

Comment: am i not going to get shot down for posting more code?

Comment: You're not supposed to include more code, you're supposed to include the *string* and what you want to do with it

Comment: @user3045351 please provide the inputs and expected outputs along with the errors or actual outputs. "Isn't working" is not enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I have amended my question to show the code in more detail. 'data' converts the result of future.results into a string and then 'data2' is a new string derived from that where the replacing is supposed to happen.

Comment: We don't need that level of detail. We need an example of what `data` is equal to and what `data2` ends up as. Ideally, we should be able to run your code ourselves and see the problem, whereas here you still haven't provided us with an example of the input.

Comment: the input is a series of URLs stored as strings in a series of text files that are then stored in a dictionary. they are of the format (roughly) www.finance.yahoo&s=STOCK+STOCK+STOCK&f=stockmetric. These are then parsed in parallel and submitted to that site. the output is called future.result, which I then convert back to a string 'data' and the another string 'data2' to do the replacing with...

Comment: sample output currently being written is of the fashion of 'b'-0.1811\r\n+0.6193\r\n-0.6916\r\n-0.752\r\n+0.1917\r\n'

Comment: @user3045351: What you're replacing there is not the literal string '\r'. You are placing the "invisible" carriage return and line feed characters. Maybe you want `.replace(r'\r','').replace(r'\n','')` instead. But probably your *real* problem lies somewhere else. Somehow these literal '\r\n' sequences are placed in your string, possibly during some kind of double-encoding

Comment: Ok great, that worked. Could you talk me through what the additional 'r' is doing though please?

Comment: Try `print 'foo\n\n\n\n\nfoo'` in a Python shell. Then try `print r'foo\n\n\n\n\nfoo'`. That should make it clear what the difference is. You need to distinguish between a string and its different representation (printed form, quoted form etc.). Also notice the difference between `'\n\n\n'` and `repr('\n\n\n')`

Comment: ok thanks. will try that tomorrow.